# Examples of Google Closure apps outside of google?

Tags: google-closure

I know that Gmail and google+ were all written using google closure, but are there any good examples of websites outside of google that have been made with google closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zoosk uses Google Closure](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/zoosks-in-a-relationship-with-google-closure/5379). I think that one reason why Closure is mostly used in-house is because it leans more on the side of handling the complexity issues of large scale web 2.0 application development over ease of use or quick learning curve. As more tools become available for building Google Closure apps, I think that you will see more adoption outside of Google. For example, there is an application generator that [creates Google Closure apps from UML models](http://glennengstrand.info/mdsd/closure).

Answer (score 12):

We use Google Closure (the compiler, the library, and the templates) quite extensively at Monetate. I'm afraid the most visible example of that, Monetate '11, is only available to our customers -- but there are at least some videos of it in action on our site, such as the ones at http://monetate.com/2011/08/say-hello-to-monetate-11-website-marketing-reinvented/ . Everything you'll see there, in the top video, is implemented in Closure on the frontend, and powered by a JSON-RPC service on the backend. (Full disclosure: I'm the awkward-talking tech lead in the bottom video :-)

So far as suggestions go, I highly recommend Mike Bolin's book, *Closure: The Definitive Guide*. We started prototyping (both in Closure and GWT) some months before it was published, and I have to say that it would have been a lot easier for us if we had our hands on a few of those chapters in the early days, particularly the one on Components. (Components are key!) I also highly recommend Ray Ryan's Google IO talk on best practices with GWT. Yes, it's about GWT, but it's also one of the best talks out there on "Rich Web Applications," and there are plenty of things that carry over to Closure. Two big ones that come to mind are (1) the importance of event buses and MVP, and (2) getting your history management right from the beginning.

Hope it helps -HJB

Comment: I've starting reading the Closure book you recommended and I've watched the video. Thanks

Comment: Michael Bolin - the author of "Closure: The Definitive Guide" - did a presentation at Google I/O 2011 called "JavaScript Programming in the Large with Closure". The recording can be found on Youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3uWx-fhjUc

Answer (score 2):

http://TinySocialBox.com

Tiny Social Box uses Google Closure Extremely Heavily.
All pages in Tiny Social Box are only made of Google closure.

If you see the networks of request and response in Tiny Social Box, you'll realize that there is only a single js file. 
So loading a page in Tiny Social Box is pretty fast.

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't it make sense to make the website a single page website since you are using google closure?

Answer (score 1):

[Mindtalk.com](http://light.mindtalk.com/) using Google Closure.

To simplify the `write > compile > test` loop and boost productivity, we write code not in pure javascript but in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and then compiled into javascript, and finally compiled using Closure Compiler, all done by writing Makefile and just type `make`. In development mode, we also using watchr to auto make when code changes.

Comment: Lovely site, but the signup process is super slow

Answer (score 1):

I know [Indeed](http://www.indeed.com/) uses it.  I went to a talk at their HQ where they were talking about it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we wrote our own website, Nemcv.com using Google Closure and ClojureScript.